# @ExceptionHandler doesn't catch HttpMessageNotReadableException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, jackson

I have the following exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExceptionHandler.class);
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        logger.warn("HttpMessageNotReadableException occurred.", e);
        throw e;
    }
```

But it doesn't catch `HttpMessageNotReadableException`?! In my logs I see (it prints spring itself):

```
2017-07-04 13:26:38,699 DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues:164 - Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'com.finvale.model.Client'
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDate from String "Invalid date": Text 'Invalid date' could not be parsed at index 0
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4f30395; line: 1, column: 103] (through reference chain: com.finvale.model.Client["birthDay"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not deserialize value of type java.time.LocalDate from String "Invalid date": Text 'Invalid date' could not be parsed at index 0
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@4f30395; line: 1, column: 103] (through reference chain: com.finvale.model.Client["birthDay"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:225)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

Is it possible to catch this exception in my ExceptionHandler ?

### P.S.

I agree that my code contains mistake. I neeed to specify type in annotation.
I changed it like this:

```
 @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
```

but I still see same behaviour.

`handle` method doesn't invoke

Comment: maybe you should not "re-throw" it!? (`throw e;`)

Comment: @xerx593  this code doesn;t invoke

Comment: ...thanks for updates, now I would ask whether `MyExceptionHandler` is correctly (spring) configured/scanned? (Can you verify in logging the initialization of ControllerAdvice)

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is for future visitors and to avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found solution:

Root cause was that there was 2 places with `@ExceptionHandler`

- Inside controller
- Inside the Separated class `MyExceptionHandler` described in question.

I moved method to `MyExceptionHandler` ans it became working.

Comment: i only have 1 doesnt work

Answer (score 10):

You have to **specify** the class that the handler needs to handle. Like:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
```

See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) for further reading for example. Or [there](http://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler-handlerexceptionresolver) for a "complete" discussion regarding spring and exception handling.

Comment: I changed code base  accordingyour advice, but behaviour was not changed

Comment: Doesnt work. wont catch it

Comment: @PhilipRego "Doesnt work" isnt a very helpful problem description. When you think you have a similar problem, but the solutions given here aren't working, then consider to write up a completely new question. Include a link to this question here, and a good [mcve] . But see ... your comment here, how does it help anyone? It worked for me back then, and 10 people upvoted the answer, so others found it helpful, too. That is all I can say about it ...

Comment: Let's people know answer need to be update it then to the full answer. You need a method with the correct params. You just posted @ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class). Also think the location of the method probably makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Change `@ExceptionHandler` to `@ExceptionHandler(value = HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)`

And instead of re-throwing same exception, its better to return a custom object containing that error message in meaningful way

Comment: already tried didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked after I imported the class.In the beginning it was not recognizing the class. But it worked after importing import org.springframework.http.converter.*;